# PHP ZF2 Unit Tests dispatch method very slow

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, zend-framework2, zend-test

I need to test a big site written in ZF2. There is 443 test and about 10000 assertions. Testing with code coverage takes 6 hours!
I think I found the problem: In controller's tests I use a dispatch method from AbstractHttpControllerTestCase. Time of execution of dispatch method is increasing after each test (from fractions of second to tens of seconds).

I use ZF 2.1.3, PHPUnit 3.7, PHP_CodeCoverage 1.2, Xdebug v2.2.1, PHP 5.4.7.

My dispatch method:

```
public function dispatch($url, $method = HttpRequest::METHOD_GET, $params = array())
{
    $s = microtime(true);

    parent::dispatch($url, $method, $params);

    $end = microtime(true) - $s;
    echo 'dis: '.$end."\n";

    return $this->getApplication()->getMvcEvent()->getResult();
}
```

parent::dispatch is method from AbstractHttpControllerTestCase.

Sample of test:

```
$result = $this->dispatch('/archive/finance/older');

$this->assertControllerName('skycontent\controller\article');
$this->assertActionName('archive');
$this->assertParamValue('older', true);
$this->assertParamValue('category', 'finance');

$vars = (array) $result->getVariables();

$this->assertArrayHasKey('archivePosts', $vars);
```

Please help.
Thanks.

---

Update:

I use process isolation and tests done in about 15 minutes (without code coverage) but I get error in the test that are marked as skipped:

```
PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed' in -:44
```

Comment: Have you tried to run each test in isolation? And `dispatch()` is in [`AbstractControllerTestCase`](https://github.com/zendframework/Component_ZendTest/blob/master/PHPUnit/Controller/AbstractControllerTestCase.php#L239) (`Zend\Test\PHPUnit\Controller`)

Comment: It works! Much faster, about 15 minutes, but I get error in the test that are skipped:

Comment: PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed' in -:44
Stack trace:
#0 -(44): serialize(Array)
#1 -(348): __phpunit_run_isolated_test()
#2 {main}

Comment: Edit your question instead (place a line at the bottom and then the updated information). The error I know, I think this has to do with storing the code-coverage data but I'm not totally sure. There must be an issue about it on the PHPUnit github page. *Edit:* Maybe this helps? [Symfony 2 + Doctrine 2 + PHPUnit 3.5: Serialization of closure exception](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5133558/367456)

Comment: Disabling backupGlobals not working.

Comment: As outlined in that answer, you need to find out which closure is the culprit and then exclude it from serializing. Otherwise you might want to turn the bug-report https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49516 into a feature request.

Answer (score 2):

Both `Zend\ServiceManager` and `Zend\EventManager` make heavy use of [closures](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php). You cannot serialize an entire application instance and expect that to work, since it would basically mean that you attempt to serialize service factories and event listeners defined as closures.

The solution may be to use a test `Bootstrap.php` like [the one of DoctrineORMModule](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/DoctrineORMModule/blob/0.7.0/tests/Bootstrap.php), which doesn't keep an application instance in memory.
Here's a simplified example:

```php
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$appConfig = require __DIR__ . '/TestConfiguration.php';

\YourModuleTest\Util\ServiceManagerFactory::setConfig($appConfig);

unset($appConfig);
```

(the `TestConfiguration` should look like a [standard mvc application's config](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/zf/release-2.1.0/config/application.config.php))

You also need the `ServiceManagerFactory`. Sample implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/blob/0.7.0/tests/DoctrineORMModuleTest/Util/ServiceManagerFactory.php) and [here](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/develop/library/Zend/Test/Util/ModuleLoader.php).

```php
namespace YourModuleTest\Util;

class ServiceManagerFactory
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected static $config;

    /**
     * @param array $config
     */
    public static function setConfig(array $config)
    {
        static::$config = $config;
    }

    /**
     * Builds a new service manager
     * Emulates {@see \Zend\Mvc\Application::init()}
     */
    public static function getServiceManager()
    {
        $serviceManager = new ServiceManager(new ServiceManagerConfig(
            isset(static::$config['service_manager']) 
                ? static::$config['service_manager'] 
                : array()
        ));

        $serviceManager->setService('ApplicationConfig', static::$config);
        $serviceManager->setFactory(
            'ServiceListener',
            'Zend\Mvc\Service\ServiceListenerFactory'
        );

        /** @var $moduleManager \Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager */
        $moduleManager = $serviceManager->get('ModuleManager');
        $moduleManager->loadModules();

        return $serviceManager;
    }
}
```

Now, wherever you want in your tests, you can:

```php
$serviceManager = \YourModuleTest\Util\ServiceManagerFactory::getServiceManager();
$application    = $serviceManager->get('Application');

$application->bootstrap();

// ...
```

With this setup, you can run tests in insulation.

On the other side, you should focus on real unit tests first, since ZF2 really simplifies how you can compose complex objects. You should also correctly setup the coverage filters so that unrelated code is not handled (that may eat up a lot of time).

Also, re-using the mvc application instance is wrong, since the helpers are not stateless, which makes it hard to reuse them.